# Frame around table but not around the caption - Spacing problem

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, framed

I am trying to add a frame around a table but keep the caption outside the frame. My current way:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{framed}
\begin{itemize}
    \item foo
    \item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{framed}
    \caption{myCaption}
    \label{myLabel}
\end{table}
```

This works but will add a lot of space between the frame and caption.
I tried to make it better using `\captionsetup[table]{...}` but I was not happy with it.
I would like to have the same spacing as for figures. I guess I could use `tabular` inside the table but this would be only a workaround I guess.

The picture may explain my problem more. "Tabelle" and "Abbildung" have a different spacing to the table / picture.
Thanks a lot!
[image: Different space when using framed.]

EDIT:
Minimal Setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{framed} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1, keepaspectratio]{universe}
        \caption{The Universe}
    \label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{framed}
\begin{itemize}
    \item foo
    \item bar
\end{itemize}
\end{framed}
        \caption{foo bar}
    \label{tab:foobar}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output of minimal setup:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. (1) A `table` is a float, and the `float` package defines a `\floatsyle` command which can take "*boxed* The body of the float is printed inside a box. The caption goes below that" (2) `tcolorbox` package is quite powerful. (3) Which package does `framed` come from? A small compileable file (MWE) will help potential answerers test out solutions that fit your use-case; otherwise it is guesswork. (4) Hand-crafted solutions with `vline` and `hline` would be possible. (4a) `\hrule` before the caption works for me, for example.

Comment: Note that frame packages typically operate outside the text area.  One can also use `\fbox` outside a minipage with a reduced width `{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}`.

Comment: @Cicada Thanks a lot! I've added a small example project from Overleaf. The result is the same. I've read something about ```tcolorbox``` but it didn´t work with Overleaf. I might try this again. Thanks a lot aready!